# Is there a way of using `std::optional` optionally for all the members in a class

Tags: c++

Consider the classes

```
struct Foo1
{
    int n;
    double m;   
};
```

and

```
struct Foo2
{
    std::optional<int> n;
    std::optional<double> m;    
};
```

In reality the number of members is greater than this. Is there a way I can templatise this to one class, something like

```
template<class T>
struct Foo
{
    T<int> n;
    T<double> m;
};
```

where if `T` is `std::optional` then `Foo` is the same as `Foo2`, and if `T` is "nothing at all" then it's the same as `Foo1`. They don't have to be formally the same, just have the same member types if you get my meaning.

So then I could write `Foo<std::optional> foo2;` in order to make all the members optional or `Foo<whatever> foo1;` to make them not optional.

I'm using C++14, although if this requires techniques beyond that standard, I'll live with it!

Comment: Large number of members in a class may make it a good candidate for decomposition.

Comment: @HarjitSingh: Downvotes don't represent "offense". They represent that someone thinks it's not a good question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write a simple switch that chooses between a type or its optional:

```
template <typename T, bool O = false>
using optionally_optional = std::conditional_t<O, std::optional<T>, T>;
```

And then, use it as follows:

```
template <bool O>
struct Foo
{
    optionally_optional<int, O> n;
    optionally_optional<double, O> m;
};
```